# Should a Web Search with Evernote results be a concern?

Tags: privacy, google, chrome, research, content-security-policy

While using a Chromium based browser (Chromodo) and doing a regular Google search, Evernote is now appearing on the side with "related results in your notes".

Does anyone know how they are doing it?

*I cannot see any additional plugins (extensions) in the list.

I am wondering if this is source of concern for security and/or privacy.  Does it send the search to the online site or it searches locally in my database.  Also, does it notify the "in notes result" to any 3rd party such as Google?

Comment: You should throw [Chromodo](https://code.google.com/p/google-security-research/issues/detail?id=704) away like a stick of dynamite.

Comment: @DeerHunter How so? Security concerns?

Comment: Long story short: Chromodo disables same-origin policy, letting third-party sites steal your cookies, wife and family jewels (not necessarily in that order).

Comment: @DeerHunter thanks, I will look further into it, might be time for a change...

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like Evernote [simultaneous search](https://blog.evernote.com/blog/2010/09/30/evernote-chrome-extension-gets-simultaneous-search/), I'd say that it will be sending the search queries you enter to the evernote service in order to provide this feature.

Whether that's a problem for you will depend on whether you're happy with Evernote seeing that information.  Obviously you trust them not to be actively malicious as you've installed their software on your system, so if you're concerned more about their privacy pratices, a good route would be to look at their published [privacy policy](https://evernote.com/legal/privacy.php) and see whether you're comforatable with the uses they could make of the data contained in your search terms

Comment: @Rory McCune Thanks for the simultaneous search link. I will review it. I had read the pricavy policy already. So privacy wise, it should be acceptable, and when or if it cannot, I can just do the search on duckduckgo and/or through disconnect search extension. Both are not allowing Evernote as far as I know from trying. And security wise? Does it open any vulnerability?